# Помогите разобраться с крэшом в икскоде

Tags: ios, xcode

После того как я меняю размер фрэйма у любой вьюшки, икскод просто падает и выдает эту ошибку. Причем другие проекты на икскоде работают нормально. Нигде похожую ошибку найти не смогла. Помогите пожалуйста

---

```
Process:               Xcode [1552]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.2.1 (11766.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11766001000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       820169454
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1552]
User ID:               502
Date/Time:             2017-02-21 11:42:11.347 +0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        1A6E852B-4D7B-D820-9C5D-11C3D447EEB7

Time Awake Since Boot: 2700 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8C1002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-11762/InterfaceBuilderKit/RemoteViews/IBIncrementalSceneUpdateTracker.m:36
Details:  Assertion failed: [self isTrackingSceneForObject:object]
Object:   <IBIncrementalSceneUpdateTracker: 0x7f862ec0ef00>
Method:   -noteObject:changedValueForKeyPath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8626e12d10>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
4   -[IBIncrementalSceneUpdateTracker noteObject:changedValueForKeyPath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
5   -[IBSceneUpdateManager noteObject:changedValueForKeyPath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
6   -[IBDocument noteChange:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
7   -[IBStoryboardDocument noteChange:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
8   -[IBDocument undoableProperty:ofMember:changedFromValue:toValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
9   -[IBDocument observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
10   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
11   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
12   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
13   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
14   _NSSetSizeValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
15   -[NSView setFrame:] (in AppKit)
16   -[NSView _actuallyUpdateFrameFromLayoutEngineForSize:origin:] (in AppKit)
17   -[NSView _updateFrameFromLayoutEngine] (in AppKit)
18   -[NSView _callUpdateFrameFromLayoutEngineOnSubviews] (in AppKit)
19   NSViewLevelLayout (in AppKit)
20   -[NSView layout] (in AppKit)
21   _NSViewLayout (in AppKit)
22   -[NSView _doLayout] (in AppKit)
23   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
24   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
25   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
26   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
27   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
28   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
29   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
30   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
31   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
32   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
33   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
34   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
35   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
36   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
37   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
38   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
39   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
40   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
41   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
42   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
43   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
44   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
45   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
46   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
47   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
48   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeIfNeededAndAllowTemporaryEngine:] (in AppKit)
49   -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutViewTree] (in AppKit)
50   -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
51   ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.6213 (in AppKit)
52   __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
53   CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) (in QuartzCore)
54   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore)
55   CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore)
56   __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.31 (in AppKit)
57   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
58   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
59   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
60   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
61   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
62   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
63   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
64   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
65   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
66   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
67   -[IBModalEventTracker trackMouseInWindow:fromEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
68   __32-[IBViewTracker trackWithEvent:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
69   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
70   -[IBDocument delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
71   -[IBSceneUpdateManager assertOnSynchronousUpdatesDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
72   __137-[IBDocument performIncrementalUpdatesAndDelayAutolayoutStatusForSceneContainingObject:allowIncrementalSceneUpdatesForSceneRoots:during:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
73   -[IBSceneUpdateManager establishIncrementalUpdateSessionForObject:duringBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
74   -[IBDocument performIncrementalUpdatesAndDelayAutolayoutStatusForSceneContainingObject:allowIncrementalSceneUpdatesForSceneRoots:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
75   -[IBViewTracker trackWithEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
76   __47-[IBViewEditor resizeChild:fromKnob:withEvent:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
77   -[IBViewEditor withConstraintDrawingHidden:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
78   -[IBViewEditor resizeChild:fromKnob:withEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
79   -[IBViewEditor interceptResizingEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
80   -[IBViewEditor interceptDecoratorActionEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
81   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController actionAreaInterceptedEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
82   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
83   -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
84   -[IBEditorCanvasFrame mouseDown:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
85   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
86   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
87   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
88   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
89   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
90   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
91   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
92   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
93   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
Application Specific Signatures:
[self isTrackingSceneForObject:object]
```

Comment: вы размер меняете в коде или в IB?

Answer (score 0):

складывается ощущение, что проблема в вашем xib. Попробуйте пересоздать его и привязать связи заново. Вызывается какой-то системный Assert из-за несоответствия типа передаваемого объекта, видимо.